# How to seek permission for external sd card?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a music player where I try to access songs from SD card. But it's showing some error related to permission. How can I make sure that the permission is granted. I am quite a beginner in android. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I am accessing the songs.

```
     public void getSongList(){

    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){

        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

I am sorting the list in the onCreate .

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //retrieve list view
    songView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    //instantiate list
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    //get songs from device
    getSongList();
    //sort alphabetically by title
    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
        public int compare(Song a, Song b){
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });
```

Even after adding the function as suggested by @hasbi I'm getting the same error. This is my logcat summary.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.john.musicplayer, PID: 2716
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.john.musicplayer/com.example.john.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2716, uid=10083 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2716, uid=10083 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:530)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:472)
                                                                            at com.example.john.musicplayer.MainActivity.getSongList(MainActivity.java:147)
                                                                            at com.example.john.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: *showing some error* is a meaningless problem description. You need to be **specific**. If it's *showing some error*, that means there's an error message that you can read; it belongs in your question, so we have that information as well. See [ask].

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry for not being specific. I've added the logcat summary

Answer (score 0):

In logcat it's showing permission denial, kindly clear apps data and recheck.Also, again check  code that is mentioned from @hasbi